# Game Design: Calculating Experience Points earned after a battle

Tags: php, math

I'm developing a simple text battle game and having some issues calculating how much XP should be earned after a battle, theres a few factors that i want to consider:

1) Players should of course earn good XP if they beat someone of the same level

2) Players should earn great XP if they beat someone of a higher level

3) Players should earn poor XP if they defeat someone of a lower level.

4) The above should scale nicely, i.e. if player A is level 10 and battles Player B who's level 9 or 11 the difference shouldn't be huge (they would of course gain more XP for defeating the level 11 character but we wouldn't expect this to be huge), but if he was to battle a level 5 or 15 this difference should be huge.

Just having trouble calculating something that works well in all scenarios, currently my XP table looks like the below:

```
Current Level   XP Needed   Increase from Last Level
1   30  0
2   65  35
3   106 41
4   154 48
5   210 56
...
10  672 123
```

In PHP my code looks like the below to calculate the XP Needed:

```
$offset = 30;
$multiplier = 1.17;
$base = $prevXp * $multiplier;

$xp = $base + $offset;
```

I've tried a few different things but i haven't been impressed with any of them, I'd like to work with calculating the difference in XP between the two players and then using some kind of multiplier but i haven't been impressed with the results so far.

Any help / input would be appreciated.

Comment: Might be a better idea to ask here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wildly subjective as to what is a "good" system.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fight method I used for a FB game I ditched.  You might find it useful.

```
public function fight(Player $attacker, Player $defender){
      $return = 'Attacking '.$defender->getName().'
';
      // if the defener has greater def than attackers attack, repel the attack
      // if the attacker has greater attack then the denfenders defense, penetrate
      if($attacker->getAttack() > $defender->getDefense()){
        $attacker->takeTemper(1);
        // penetration -- that's what she said!!!
        // figure out how much to damage each player
        $dmgDefender = rand(5, 25);
        $defender->takeHP($dmgDefender);
        $dmgAttacker = rand(0, 10);
        // figure out the reward
        // give between 1 and 5 XP and 10% of the defenders money
        $gainedXP = rand(1, 5);
        $attacker->addXP($gainedXP);
        $gainedMoney = floor($defender->getMoney() * .1);
        $attacker->addMoney($gainedMoney);
        $defender->takeMoney($gainedMoney);
        $return .= 'You won the fight and gained '.$gainedXP.' XP and $'.$gainedMoney.'
';
        if($dmgAttacker > 0){
          $return .= 'Unfortuantely you took '.$dmgAttacker.' damage in the fight.  The good news is you did '.$dmgDefender.' damage to '.$defender->getName().'
';
          $attacker->takeHP($dmgAttacker);
        }
        // check if the player leveled
        $nextLevelXP = $this->_level->levelXP( $attacker->getLevel() + 1 );
        if( ( $attacker->getXP() >= $nextLevelXP ) ){
          $gainedFounderPoints = $this->gainLevel($attacker);
          $return .= 'You gained a level';
          if($gainedFounderPoints > 0)
            $return .= ' and '.$gainedFounderPoints.IMG_FOUNDER_POINT;
          $return .= '
';
        }
      } else {
        // attack deflected
        $return .= 'The attack was deflected by '.$defender->getName().'
';
        // reward defender -- how about 10% of the attackers money?
        $reward = ceil($attacker->getMoney() * .1);
        if($reward > 0){
          // demerit attacker
          $attacker->takeMoney($reward);
          $defender->giveMoney($reward);
          $return .= 'You lost $'.$reward.'
';
        } else {
          // the attacker is broke ... take his XP!!! -- 1 percent
          $reward = ceil($attacker->getXP() * .01);
          $attacker->takeXP($reward);
          $defender->addXP($reward);
          $return .= 'You lost '.$reward.' XP
';
        }
      }
      // save data
      $attacker->save();
      $defender->save();

      // output
      return $return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is kind of simple but it fits your criteria

```
xpGain = getbasexp(); //whatever you were doing before
xpGain *= opponentxp * 1.0 / playerxp;
```